# How to force update on a read only property?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to automatically calculate a total value on my object.
Let's say my object is:

```cs
public class Sale
{
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double Total { get { return Amount * Price; } }
}
```

I have two `Entry` on my page so the user can type the `Amount` and the `Price` values, and a `Label` to show the `Total` value:

```xml
<Entry Placeholder="Amount"
       ReturnType="Done"
       Keyboard="Numeric"
       Text="{Binding MySale.Amount, Mode=OneWayToSource, StringFormat='{}{0:N0}'}"/>

<Entry Placeholder="Price"
       ReturnType="Done"
       Keyboard="Numeric"
       Text="{Binding MySale.Price, Mode=OneWayToSource, StringFormat='{}{0:N0}'}"/>

<Label Text="{Binding MySale.Total, StringFormat='{}R$ {0:N2}'}"/>
```

The `BindingContext` is correctly defined as my view model, and the `MySale` object implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```cs
private Sale _mySale;
public Sale MySale
{
    get { return _mySale; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _mySale, value); } // The SetProperty is defined in my BaseViewModel
}
```

The problem is that when I change the value of the entries, the value of the label is not updated. I even tried to manually assign the `Amount` and the `Price` values to the entries texts when the controls are unfocused, but it also didn't work.

I'm not sure if it changes anything, but my application is a MVVM Xamarin.Forms app.

**-- EDIT --**
This is my `BaseViewModel` class:

```cs
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string title = string.Empty;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref title, value); }
    }

    bool isBusy = false;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return isBusy; }
        set { SetProperty(ref isBusy, value); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to raise `PropertyChanged("Total")` whenever `Amount` or `Price` are set

Comment: but my BaseViewModel already raises `PropertyChanged`... I will add the code to the question

Comment: `Sale` doesn't inherit from `BaseViewModel`, and even if it did it is not calling `PropertyChanged` for any of its' properties.

Comment: the binding context of my page is a view model that inherits from `BaseViewModel`, and the setter of `MySale` object (in this exact view model) calls `SetProperty`, which raises `PropertyChanged` on the `BaseViewModel`... that's the same, isn't it?

Comment: that will **only** raise the event if `MySale` is assigned.  The individual properties of `Sale` do not inherit that behavior.  You have to implement `INotifiyPropertyChanged` on each class and call `SetProperty` on each property that you want to trigger a UI update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you set the value of `Amount` or `Price` you can raise mulitple `PropertyChanged` events

```
public class Sale : BaseViewModel
{
    private double amount;
    private double price;

    public double Amount
        get { return amount; }
        set { SetProperty(ref amount, value);
              this.OnPropertyChanged("Total"); }

    public double Price
        get { return price; }
        set { SetProperty(ref price, value); 
              this.OnPropertyChanged("Total"); } 

    public double Total { get { return Amount * Price; } }
}
```